# Detect screen-lock in shell/c++

Tags: 14.04, gnome, lock-screen

I have a cross-platform application that runs on Ubuntu 14.04 (GNOME). There I need to determine if the screensaver is active or not and if the screen is locked or not.

I found out that I can get the screensaver info with: `gnome-screensaver-command -q`

But I cannot seem to figure out how I can detect a screen lock. For example on Unity I can use:

```
gdbus call -e -d com.canonical.Unity -o /com/canonical/Unity/Session -m com.canonical.Unity.Session.IsLocked
```

but that's a Unity-specific item. So any ideas on how to get this info on Gnome machines?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? :)

Comment: @Noitidart Actually I did, I'll log it as the aswer :)

Comment: Thank you very much Mathieu! Is this solution Ubuntu specific? Or would it work on other linuxes too? Im trying to look for a cross linux solution but was starting with Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence contains the current status of the user session.

It can be called by this:

```
gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.SessionManager -o /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence status
```

Quick bash test:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
 echo "PRESENCE "
gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.SessionManager -o /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence status
        echo -e "\n"
        sleep 1
done
```

For example in Qt:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("sh", QStringList() << "-c"<< "gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.SessionManager -o /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence status");
process.waitForFinished();
result = QString::fromLatin1(process.readAllStandardOutput());
int state = result.remove("(<uint32 ").remove(">,)").toInt();
if(state != 0) {
    // user not active!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answer returns an error on Ubuntu 18.04 because the call wants dots instead of slashes.  Including error output for future searches:

Error calling:

```
$ gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.SessionManager -o /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence ss
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface '/org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence'
(According to introspection data, you need to pass 'ss')
```

Example of working syntax:

```
$ gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.SessionManager -o /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get org.gnome.SessionManager.Presence status
(<uint32 0>,)
```

Output when locked:

```
$ sleep 10; gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.SessionManager -o /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get org.gnome.SessionManager.Presence status
(<uint32 3>,)
```

Docs https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html#org.gnome.SessionManager.Presence